# Button hover coloring

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Edited after resolution for clarity.

I'd like to change the hover color over a button from the default blue to another color. I would like to do this without having to completely redefine all the CSS for the button. I only want to override the hover color, leaving the remaining defaults in place.

Pics:

Normally, it's this: [image] Hovering, it's this: [image]

I want to change the highlight color on hover.

EDIT:

Have tried:

```
.Cancel:hover
    {
        background: linear-gradient(black, white); //Tried these separately
        background-color:Red;
    }
```

and the button markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPprGrdsCancelRefresh" runat="server" Text="Cancel/Refresh" CssClass="Cancel" />
```

The linear gradient appears to not be doing anything, and the background color changes the color of the button, not the mask over the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class does that:

```
button:hover {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

However, styling form controls is usually tricky. If you're trying to let the browser render the buttons with its default styles, then just change the background-color on hover, it's not going to work; other properties (like borders) will also change, [as this live example demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/cGRbC/). You have to choose between letting the browser and operating system decide how the control will look, on all states, or create your own styles for every state.

Comment: I updated my main post to reflect this, but background-color is not what I want. That changes the color of the button itself, rather than the highlight mask placed over it on hover.

Comment: What do you mean "mask"? I used background-color as an example, but you can use any CSS properties.

Comment: I don't know what the property is called. I'd show pictures if I could. played with all of the color properties intellisense shows, and none of them touch it. The button in this examples displays the behavior I'm talking about [link](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_textbox)

Comment: I included a link to an example in the question.

Comment: I think I unsderstand now. Styling form controls is complicated; you have to choose between an appearance 100% defined by the browser/OS, or 100% custom.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks. If you put that info in an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
button:hover{
//style color here
}
```